# How to select on folder structure in a query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID  Path                                Checked
1   /data/docs/overview.doc             1
2   /data/docs/list.txt                 1
3   /data/docs/archived/overview.doc    0
4   /data/docs/archived/management.doc  0
5   /data/systemlist.txt                1
```

The challenge I have with this is that I need a list of files in the /data/docs folder for instance.

My query result would be:

```
ID  Path
1   /data/docs/overview.doc
2   /data/docs/list.txt
```

I created several queries, but all resulting in errors because of incorrect syntax or to much info.

One of them is where I selected ID and Path with a like on path, but then I also get the ID's 3 and 4, because the also have the first part of the path.

Comment: Could you provide a couple of your query attempts and the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a third approach:

```
WHERE path REGEXP '^/data/docs/[^/]+$'
```

(Mine is shorter, but not necessarily faster.)

Comment: Thanks for this line. It's the easiest to implement this one in my code, and done as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE path
(
  path_id INTEGER,
  path_name VARCHAR (255),
  path_checked INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO path VALUES (1, '/data/docs/overview.doc', 1);
INSERT INTO path VALUES (2, '/data/docs/archived/overview.doc', 0);

SELECT * 
FROM path
WHERE path_name LIKE '/data/docs/%' 
AND LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path_name, '/', 4)) = 0;
```

If there is anything after a 4th slash, it must be a file and won't be accepted. (Note: untested - both [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) and [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) acting up on my mobile device today - will verify ASAP - apologies, but I believe that the concept is on the right track!).

Comment: (You were missing a /%)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and +1 for the elegant regexp! I keep forgetting MySQL has `REGEXP,` but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740006/mysql-regexp-performance-question) -  `LIKE` is more efficient

Comment: You are welcome.  Yes, `LIKE` is faster than `RLIKE`, and `LIKE` can use an index in some cases.  So _probably_ your Answer is the fastest, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Using just the `like` clause:

```
select ID, Path
from   paths
where  Path     like "/data/docs/%"
and    Path not like "/data/docs/%/%"
order by 1,2
```

- first `like` clause searches for anything under the '/data/docs/' directory
- second (negated) `like` clause eliminates any files that contain a forward slash (`/`), ie, it eliminates sub-directories

Results of the above:

```
ID  Path
--  -----------------------
1   /data/docs/overview.doc
2   /data/docs/list.txt
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://rextester.com/MVO97644)